# Add dependency in setup project

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer, setup-project

I have windows application . And added a set up project for the application. But the application require another software to be installed.
When installing my app it should install the other software if it does not exists.
 I have the installer for the prerequisite with me. using visual studio 2010. How it is possible. Waiting for responses.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think this question could be usefull for you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796583/installing-3rd-party-applications-in-c-sharp-installer

Comment: Please refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373225/visual-studio-deployment-with-third-party-setups

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your responses. The issue get solved. I have created a bootstrapper package and add it as a  prerequisite in my set up project.
pls refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx  This link will help in this kind of issue

Thanks